# Replace in Array

Tags: java

im trying make one replace in string from a array but this dont work

```
dna[i].replace('T', 'C');
```

and with this way work?

```
"ATCTA".replace('T', 'C');
```

why dont work with array, how i can use use a replace in array[]

Now i have other problem, i want use various replaces in original string, how i can mahe this????

Comment: Is `dna` an array of Strings or an array of chars?

Comment: What exactly was the error or your expectation - as you can see from the answers, we have two competing theories already ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 String dna[] = {"ATCTA"};
 int i = 0;
 dna[i] = dna[i].replace('T', 'C');
 System.out.println(dna[i]);
```

This works as expected. Double check your code if you follow a similiar pattern.

---

You may have expected, that `dna[i].replace('T', 'C');` changes the content of the cell `dna[i]` directly. This is not the case, the String will not be changed, `replace` will return a new String where the char has been replaced. It's necessary to assign the result of the `replace` operation to a variable.

---

To answer your last comment:

Strings are immutable - you can't change a single char inside a String object. All operations on Strings (substring, replace, '+', ...) always create new Strings.

A way to make more than one replace is like this:

```
dna[i] = dna[i].replace('T', 'C').replace('A', 'S');
```

Comment: This would make a one-element array of Strings, and `dna[i]` references the first (only) element. I think the OP was confusing a String object and an array of characters, not an array of Strings.

Comment: @Andreas, I think he has an array of characters, not an array of strings.

Comment: I thought he had an array of Strings, not of characters.

Comment: @Dean, my guess is that the OP is confusing the two.

Comment: I'd imagine that the OP is actually getting tripped up by the immutability of String. I would assume that he is trying to do just `dna[i].replace(...);` instead of `dna[i]=dna[i].replace(...);`, which of course leads to the contents of the array not being modified.

Comment: Now i have other problem, i want use various replaces in original string, how i can mahe this????

Answer (score 3):

An array is just a data structure that holds data.  It doesn't support any operations on that data.  You need to write the algorithms to work on the data yourself.

A `String` is basically a char array with some methods that you can call on that.  The `replace()` method is one of them.

The method you want would look something like this:

```
static void replace(char[] arr, char find, char replace) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == find) {
            arr[i] = replace;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
replace(dna, 'T', 'C');
```

That would replace the first instance of `T` in the array with a `C`.