# Swap letters in a string

Tags: java

I need to swap letters in a string with the following rules:

- A is replaced by T
- T is replaced by A
- C is replaced by G
- G is replaced by C

For example: `ACGTA` should become `TGCAT`

What would be the best way to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250405/replace-in-array)

Comment: There are more compact representation of DNA strings that uses only 2 bits per base. If this is for a serious research project, you may want to consider those options instead of using 16-bit `char` per base (especially if your DNA strings can have millions of bases and more).

Comment: I thought *real* DNA decrypts had other letters too, used to represent particular types of uncertainty. I remember being quite surprised when I found out, but it's not really that startling when you consider how they do sequencing. Only just starting to get proper digital-equivalent sequencers coming online now AIUI.

Comment: A *lookup table* can be used, given the small alphabet of DNA, even with the ambiguity codes noted by @DonalFellows. It's five years after the question, but I've added a better answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Searching for [`java "A to T, T to A"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+%22A+to+T%2C+T+to+A%22) found this [suggestion](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10183549#10183549):

```
String sequence = "AATTTCTCGGTTTCAAT";
sequence = sequence.replace("A", "t")
                   .replace("T", "a")
                   .replace("C", "g")
                   .replace("G", "c")
                   .toUpperCase();
System.out.println(sequence);
```

This is a simple and concise solution that works for your specific situation and will have acceptable performance if your DNA strings are relatively short. For a more general solution for handling large amounts of data you should iterate over the characters one by one and build a new string. Or as polygenelubricants pointed out - consider a storage format that only uses 2 bits per base instead of 16.

Comment: Why the lowercase replacement and then toUpperCase?

Comment: @fielding: To avoid replacing the same character twice (A -> T -> A).

Comment: Note that this simple approach traverses the string multiple times. A single iteration is possible, and may increase speed. A single iteration can also eliminate the need to lose the original letter case, which is sometimes used to communicate information.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for a more general solution like this:

```
public String tr(String original, String trFrom, String trTo) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); ++i) {
    int charIndex = trFrom.indexOf(original.charAt(i));
    if (charIndex >= 0) {
      sb.append(trTo.charAt(charIndex));
    } else {
      sb.append(original.charAt(i));
    }
  }

  return sb.toString(); 
}
```

Calling the function like this would give the result you need:

```
tr("ACGTA", "ATCG", "TAGC")
```

So the function is pretty much the same as unix tr utility:

```
echo ACGTA | tr ATCG TAGC
```

Answer (score 4):

Like I [explained yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250405/replace-in-array/3250444#3250444), Strings are immutable, you can't change a String, you have to create a new one and replace the old one.

You can solve your problem like this:

```
String s = "ACGTA";
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
for (char c:s.toCharArray()) {
  switch(c) {
    case 'A': sb.append('T');break;
    case 'T': sb.append('A');break;
    case 'C': sb.append('G');break;
    case 'G': sb.append('C');break;
    default: //handle error here -> invalid char in String
  }
}
s = sb.toString();
```

The advantage of this solution is that you just don't create too many String objects (every 'replace' operation creates a new String and this can kill performance if you have to revert *a lot* of dna sequences)

---

Here is more performant version based on the very helpful comments from [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) and [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185541/rsp):

```
String s = "ACGTA";
char[] reverse = new char[s.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
  switch(s.charAt(i)) {
    case 'A': reverse[i] = 'T';break;
    case 'T': reverse[i] = 'A';break;
    case 'C': reverse[i] = 'G';break;
    case 'G': reverse[i] = 'C';break;
    default: //handle error here -> invalid char in String
  }
}
s = new String(reverse);
```

Comment: -1: But you can assign a new String (that is the result of applying the transformation to the old String) to the variable containing the old String. Don't be excessively obtuse.

Comment: ok thanks too, your yesterday solution helpme but i had a problem with replace all, but now works with Mark Byers solution

Comment: @Donal - hope you had at least a look at the referenced question and answer before you downvoted. The core of this answer is the solution to the replacing problem. Yesterday, mac135 seemed to be focussed on changing the original String, so I had the feeling, this would start again.

Comment: If performance is an issue, it might be better to change the `char[]` in place and use that to build your result at the last step.

Comment: @Donal certainly you may assign the new String to the same variable; however this does not change the fact that you are creating additional strings unnecessarily, StringBuilder is more efficient.

Comment: +1; but do keep in mind that DNA strings can be incredibly long (millions of `char` or more), so while `for-each` on `.toCharArray()` is most readable and acceptable in most cases, it may not be in this case (since it doubles the space requirement).

Comment: If the data is in a `String`, all operations are going to increase the space requirement. If they're in a `StringBuilder` then you've only got a restricted set of operations available. The real solution, since only char-for-char substitutions are performed, is to keep everything in a char array and do the processing manually (well, switch inside loop) so you never copy anything or have any silly overheads.

Comment: @Donal - as shown in my added 'high-performance' solution already.

Answer (score 0):

DNA has a small alphabet. You can use a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), replacing some statements with a simple array indexing.

This approach:

- Traverses the sequence only once.
- Eliminates the conditional statements.
- Can be stable in terms of letter case, which is sometimes used to communicate information in DNA sequences.
- Can handle IUPAC ambiguity codes.
- Can handle gaps.
- Can easily provide a *reverse complement*.

First, you need a lookup table.

```
private static final String COMPLEMENT_TABLE 
  // 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
  = "                                " // 0-31
  + "             -                  " // 32-63
  + " TVGH  CD  M KN   YSAABWXR      " // 64-95
  + " tvgh  cd  m kn   ysaabwxr      "; // 96-127
  //  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

private static final byte[] COMPLEMENT_TABLE_BYTES 
  = COMPLEMENT_TABLE.getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII );
```

Then, you can find the complement's bases by a simple table lookup.

```
public static byte[] complement( byte[] sequence ) {
    int length = sequence.length;
    byte[] result = new byte[ length ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
        result[i] = COMPLEMENT_TABLE_BYTES[ sequence[i] ];
    }

    return result;
}
```

If desired for convenience with small sequences, you can provide a method that accepts and returns a String.

```
public static String complement( String sequence ) {
    byte[] complementBytes = complement( 
      sequence.getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII ));
    return new String( complementBytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII );
}
```

The reverse complement can be computed in the same loop.

```
public static byte[] reverseComplement( byte[] sequence ) {
    int length = sequence.length;
    byte[] result = new byte[ length ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
        result[ (length - i) - 1] = COMPLEMENT_TABLE_BYTES[ sequence[i] ];
    }

    return result;
}

public static String reverseComplement( String sequence ) {
    byte[] complementBytes = reverseComplement( 
      sequence.getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII ));
    return new String( complementBytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII );
}
```

Using your example sequence:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sequence = "ACGTA";

    String complementSequence = complement( sequence );
    System.out.println( String.format( 
       "complement(%s) = %s", sequence, complementSequence ));

    String reverseComplementSequence = reverseComplement( sequence );
    System.out.println( String.format( 
      "reverseComplement(%s) = %s", sequence, reverseComplementSequence ));
}
```

We get this output:

```
complement(ACGTA) = TGCAT
reverseComplement(ACGTA) = TACGT
```