# How can I replace certain characters within a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a program that reads an input (a String) and prints that String reversed. Now, I need to read through the reversed String and replace all of the "A"s with "T"s, the "T"s with "A"s, the "G"s with "C"s and the "C"s to "G"s. So basically, the "complement". I tried to use multiple lines with a replace function but once the "A"s are turned into "T"s, it will replace all of those into "A"s so there are no "T"s at all. How can I replace the characters so that they do not override each other?

Here is my code if it helps! I don't have any functions to get the "complement" yet, but here is what I'm working with.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DNA {    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a DNA sequence: ");

        Scanner read;
        read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = read.next();               

        String reverse="";
        for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Here is the reversed sequence: ");
        System.out.println(reverse);
    }    
}
```

Comment: One way would be to use a temporary letter, like: replace A with X, T with A, then X with T. Similarly for the other pair.

Comment: @Logan you can iterate over the String and use switch case for each char

Comment: A previous question about exactly the same topic was posted and very well [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254387/4375327).

Comment: @Amessihel I wish I had found this earlier! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code sample that you can try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class DNA {    
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Please input a DNA sequence: ");

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = read.next();               

    String reverse="";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);
    }
    for (char c: input.toCharArray()) {  // user 'reverse' to operate on reversed string
        switch (c) {
            case 'A' : sb.append('T'); break;
            case 'T' : sb.append('A'); break;
            case 'G' : sb.append('C'); break;
            case 'C' : sb.append('G'); break;
            default : sb.append(""); break; // handle you're exceptions here
        }
    }
    System.out.println("x: " + sb);

    System.out.println("Here is the reversed sequence: ");
    System.out.println(reverse);

    read.close();
}}
```

Well, `switch-case` is a kind of mapping technique which will map your `case` (as key) with it's values. In this case:
I am replacing 'A' with 'T' where the string contains 'A' by appending into the `StringBuilder` (to create a new string) and then `break;` which is a mandatory statement for single time execution only.
And the default keyword is for `default case`, which means if all of the cases are unsatisfied to be executed then the `default` case is called, you can do whatever you want to do by default if no case, condition matched.
Well, for your last question, You can make it generic if the problem states some pattern; if not you, unfortunately have to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your reverse string to a char array like this:

```
char[] charArr = reverse.toCharArray();
```

Then you can iterate through it and change the characters that you want:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++){
        if(charArr[i] == 'A'){
            charArr[i] = 't';
        }   
    }
```

At the end you can convert the char array back to a string like this:

```
String str = new String(charArr);
```

Comment: That is smart to convert it to lower-case so that it wouldn't be overwritten. Then I could just use .toUppercase() on the result

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace method, but change your values to a "temporary" character. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

- Replace T -> x
- Replace A -> T
- Replace x -> A

Repeat for all your pairs.